# Анимация DOM-узла в момент удаления его из DOM

Tags: javascript, css3, dom, css-animation

В DOM-записывается новый элемент, затем по истечению 2-х секунд он удаляется. Как анимировать этот элемент в момент удаления из DOM? Например, чтобы блок равномерно исчезал словно растворяется. Интересует наиболее правильный и простой пример.

```
var warningEl = document.createElement('div');
warningEl.setAttribute('class', 'warning');
var message = document.createTextNode('Какое-то сообщение'); 
warningEl.appendChild(message);
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
container.appendChild(warningEl);
function animate() {
        container.removeChild(warningEl);
      }
        setTimeout(animate, 2000);
    }
```

css

```
.warning {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: opacity;//какое свойство анимировать
    transition-duration: 2s;//длительность анимации
    transition-timing-function: ease;//на сколько быстро должно изменяться значение стилевого свойства для которого применяется эффект перехода
}
```

Comment: есть такое событие `transitionend`... говорит само за себя. Подпишитесь на него, и удалите блок после возникновения этого события

Comment: "подписаться на него", вы имеете введу использовать метод addEventListener() ? Что-то не получается разобраться.

Comment: да, использовать `addEventListener`

Comment: никак не получается, посмотрите, что не так??? https://jsfiddle.net/bqymto6f/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
submit.addEventListener('click', handler);


function handler() {
//создаём блок с сообщением
  var el = document.createElement('span');
  el.className= 'span';
  el.innerText = 'Какой-то текст с сообщением';
  container.appendChild(el);
  setTimeout(function(){
   el.classList.add('animate'); 
  },2000)
  el.addEventListener("transitionend", hide)
}
function hide (event){
var target = event.target;
container.removeChild(target)
}
```

```css
.span {
  display:block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: #F08080;
  color: floralwhite;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition-duration: 5s;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.animate {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Ок</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Это же Вы установили задержку в 2 секунды

Comment: Не так сформулировал вопрос. Хотел спросить, почему задержка устанавливается на добавление класса animate. Но это и так очевидно "Событие transitionend срабатывает, когда CSS transition закончил свое выполнение. "